# How can I read a JWT Token on an [AllowAnonymous] EndPoint in EF .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an endpoint that I want public but also perform some actions if the user is logged in. If I add an AuthorizeAttribute, the claims are there, but if I make it AllowAnonymous, the claims are empty.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize("Read")] //I want this to be AllowAnonymous
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<string>>> Get()
    {
        //This only works if I use [Authorize("Read")]
        var subject = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        return Ok(new List<string>() { "A", "B" });
    }
```

I hope I explained that clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpContext.User is not available when you are using AllowAnonymous (it's null).  You can however hack around this by getting the ClaimsPrincipal using the AuthenticateAsync() method.  Be sure to change the AuthenticationScheme to whatever scheme you are using (this example is JWT).

```
var auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
if (auth.Succeeded)
{
   var claimsPrincipal = auth.Principal;
   var subject = claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
   // use the subject claim as needed (actual value is "subject.Value")
}
```

I have used this code on Asp.Net Core 2 and 3.1 using JWT, so your mileage may vary if you use something else.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.